# How to specify overwrite = T in dplyr::semi_join() against Oracle

Tags: r, oracle, dplyr, dbplyr, r-dbi

As I'm doing some analysis in R, I need to be able to do a semi_join() where I get all values in an Oracle database table where there's a matching row in a local R tibble.

Normally, I'd do that like this:

```
con  <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "THEDATABASE")
db_tbl  <- tbl(con, in_schema("OTHER_USER", "table_I_care_about")

local_tbl  <- tibble(x = 1:5, y = 5:10)

new_tbl_from_db  <- db_tbl %>%
    semi_join(local_tbl, by = 'x', copy =T)
```

Sometimes this works. But often, I get this error:
`Error: Table "dbplyr_001" exists in database, and both overwrite and append are FALSE` (Of course, it's not always dbplyr_001--it could be just about any number).

If I look in my schema in the database, I see that a table named `dbplyr_001` exists, which I'm not surprised about. I don't mind dbplyr writing little temporary tables. I've tried manually inserting values into this table, which works fine too.

What I can't figure out how to do is to specify `overwrite=TRUE`. I've tried passing that as a further argument to `semi_join()`, but still get the same error. Is there an easy way to pass `overwrite=TRUE` or `append=TRUE` via `dplyr::semi_join()`?

Comment: This could be a dupe of [dbplyr#438](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/438) or need [odbc#361](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/pull/361). Check that you have odbc-1.2.3 and dbplyr-1.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

While not a direct solution, three other options are:

- to delete the remote table
- to copy the local table to the database where you name the table
- to pass the ID values using `%in%`

Code for each of these below. Note that I work with an SQL server connection, so some of the database syntax may be different. Several of these approaches require the `DBI` package, but `dbplyr` is probably using this so you probably have this installed already.

#### 1 Deleting the local table

The idea here is to create a text string that contains the command to drop the table in the database. This command is then executed in the database using `dbExecute` from `DBI` package.

```r
delete_table <- function(db_connection, db, schema, tbl_name){
  # remove table if it exists
  removal_query <- glue::glue("IF OBJECT_ID('{db}.{schema}.{tbl_name}', 'U') IS NOT NULL\n",
                              "DROP TABLE {db}{schema}.{tbl_name};")
  result <- DBI::dbExecute(db_connection, as.character(removal_query))
```

#### 2 Copy the local table

The `DBI` package also includes functionality to write a local table directly to the database.

```r
copy_r_to_sql <- function(db_connection, db, schema, sql_table_name, r_table_name){
  
    DBI::dbWriteTable(db_connection,
                      DBI::Id(catalog = db,
                              schema = schema,
                              table = sql_table_name),
                      r_table_name)
```

Note that you'll need version 1.1.0 or later of the DBI package. Previous versions had trouble writing to user specified schema.

#### 3 Pass ID values

If there are only a small number of IDs in your local table then you could pass them as part of an `%in%` clause.

```r
id_list = local_table %>% select(x) %>% unlist()

new_tbl_from_db = db_tbl %>%
  filter(x %in% id_list)
```

This will put all the IDs into the remote WHERE clause. If you then call `show_query(new_tbl_from_db)` you should expect to see something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM db.schema.tbl
WHERE x IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ....)
```

Other dbplyr helper functions on [GitHub](https://github.com/simon-anasta/dbplyr_helpers)

Comment: I've been using solution #3 as a work around, which is fine for `semi_join()`. It's not much help for left and inner joins, though. I think #1 would be ideal. Of course, I don't always know what dplyr is going to name the new table, so I'm left with a similar problem: run the original dplyr code, see what error I get. Try to drop the table, then re-rerun my code, hoping that the help table name won't change. This is why I'd like to be able to specify `overwrite=T` in the original join--I don't want to have to think about it.

Comment: I agree that `overwrite=T` would be ideal. If you are doing a left or inner join then you probably want the data from your local table to be in the database. Perhaps solution #2 would be more suitable in these cases.